# Is it possible for C# generic to be covariant and contravariant?

Tags: c#

I have read some content on variance, and want to make sure I fully get it. My understanding is that covariant is implicit conversion of the more-derived type to less and contravariance is the opposite. I further believe that covariance corresponds to the out keyword of the generic type definition. For example IEnumerable interface definition uses out to export the result of an argument, while IComperable's interface definition uses the in keyword to receive a value. I have not seen a generic type which does both, and don't see why it may not be possible. What am I missing? 
I also read about the array[] support of variance and how there is a runtime check to make sure the types are the same.

Comment: One means the type only goes in (arguments) the other means it only comes out (return), thus it doesn't make sense for anything to be both.  If it goes in and out then it's invariant which is the default.

Comment: if something was both `in T`  and `out T` (so: `<in out T>`), then the only thing that satisfies **both** simultaneously would be `T`... but that is what you get if you just use `<T>`. What scenario do you see where it could be both *and be meaningful* for the same `T`?

Comment: If a type is both contra- and covariant, it allows a type as long as it's as least as derived *and* at most as derived as the original type. The only type that matches that is the original type, so it would have the same effect as no variance at all. And if you go by a definition were both directions are allowed at the same time, then any type would qualify, so it would be the same as using `object`. In no case is it meaningful.

Comment: @juharr that's really just a statement of how it is *used*; what it *means* is more complex, and involves talking about where reference equality assignment is legal in various directions

Comment: @All- Ok I got my answer. in/out are added notations to implement variance or implicit conversion. A in and out scenario is mute and meaningless; the only case which satisfies such a relationship would the actual type or object. Got it; thank you so much.

Comment: I believe in theory you can have a type parameter which is both co and contravariant but it would imply the type was phantom i.e. your type would never actually be given a value of the associated type. I don't think C# allows you to express that however.

Comment: @maverick small point: it isn't just "implicit conversion" - it is more restrictive than that - it needs to be an *identity preserving* conversion  - essentially a type cast that is so obviously true (to the compiler) that it doesn't need to be type-checked. Implicit conversion operators aren't allowed here, for example.

Comment: @MarcGravell- I see; ok got it. Thanks.